# Edge developer window automatically pops up

Tags: microsoft-edge, developer-tools, blazor-client-side

I am doing some web development using Blazor Wasm framework.
I use Edge for debugging. For some reason the browser automatically pops up the following dev page, meanwhile the startup page is in loading status for 20-30 seconds.

[image]

Did you experience anything like this or can you suggest anything for fix?

Comment: That's because Visual Studio's debugger opens it for you automatically.

Comment: Can you please tell me why does it happen and how can I switch it off? (It completely ruins my normal browser experience)

Comment: The VS is closed completely but the Edge's debug window keeps popping up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps when you choose a browser to debugger the Application, you are adding the arguments to open the devtools.

For example, I'm using visual studio 2019, click the down arrow to the right of "IIS Express", and select the "Browse With..." option. The "Browse With" dialog box will open. Click the "Add" button.

Then, in the *Program* field, enter the path to Microsoft Edge. In the *Arguments* field, enter the command line switch to open devtools, `--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs`. In the *Friendly Name* field, enter something descriptive, for example, `Edge Bate w/ DevTools`.

[image]

After that, when we select this option to browse the website, it will open the website with devtools, like this:

[image]

[image]

So, check your Visual Studio, and try to re-add the browser without arguments.

Comment: Finally restarting the machine solved the issue. Btw thanks for the reply, it is very useful comment.